# When a company sells a subsidiary or some of its assets, does the market reacts negatively?

Tags: stock-markets, online-trading

When a company sells a subsidiary or some of its assets to pay off debts or refinance, does the market reacts negatively?
I assume it is always negative as it reduces the company size and indicates its financials is not in good condition, right?

Comment: If you sold an asset to repay a debt, why would the "company size" change? The bottom line on the balance sheet remains the same and the future liabilities (interest payments) shrink. The asset may or may not have future revenue, which may or may not have had a potential to offset the future liabilities, but your question is way too generic to consider that.

Answer (score 2):

How the market reacts depends on how long the experts have been waiting for this to happen.

- If everybody knew it was going to happen, and they wanted it to happen, the price could go up after they finally make the move.
- If everybody hoped it wouldn't be necessary, then the price might drop.
- Or the price could stay the same if the sale was viewed neutrally.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all a foregone conclusion.  Trading an asset for debt could be net zero.  If it's a crap asset it might be positive (in terms of sentiment, not value, though it could be either or both).  If the sale done in a rush and/or considered the wrong move it might be negative.  It depends.